# Django : Parsing Json data to template

Tags: python, json, django, api

Just wondering how I correctly parse my json data from my views.py function to my template so it can be accessed within my templates as I am looking to create a table using the data and further iterate on it. Data looks like so :

```
{"meta": {"limit": 25, "cache-expiry": 3600}, "objects": [{"name": "Pizza Hut delivery", "locality": "Norwich", "website_url": null, "cuisines": [], "region": "Norfolk", "long": 1.27727303158181, "phone": "01603 488900", "postal_code": null, "categories": ["other", "restaurant"], "has_menu": false, "country": "United Kingdom", "lat": 52.6564553358682, "id": "00388fe53e4c9f5e897d", "street_address": null, "resource_uri": "/v1_0/venue/00388fe53e4c9f5e897d/"}, {"name": "Thai Lanna", "locality": "Norwich", "website_url": "http://www.thailannanorwich.co.uk", "cuisines": [], "region": "Norfolk", "long": 1.2788060400004, "phone": "01603 625087", "postal_code": "NR2 1AQ", "categories": ["other", "restaurant"], "has_menu": true, "country": "United Kingdom", "lat": 52.6273547550005, "id": "0452369b7789e15bb624", "street_address": "24 Bridewell Alley", "resource_uri": "/v1_0/venue/0452369b7789e15bb624/"},
```

I have tried using urls but haven't had any luck beyond simply doing it like so:

```
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json')
```

but that simply prints the whole json api data to the screen. Any suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use [`loads()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads) to decode the json string to the python data:

```
return render(request, 'my-template.html', json.loads(data))
```

Or, to get only the part of the data:

```
decoded_data = json.loads(data)
return render(request, 'my-template.html',
                       {'objects': decoded_data['objects']})
```

And then in your template do something like this:

```
<ul>
{% for obj in objects %}
    <li>{{ obj.name }} - {{ obj.locality }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: What and then i can just call the variable data?

Comment: Yep. I added the example.

Comment: I'm getting thrown an error saying: expected string or buffer

Comment: How do you get the `data` variable?  Is it a string?  Or may be it is an already decoded json?

Comment: No problem was my mistake. If its not to much trouble and you have the time how do I then go about adding the data we just farmed into a bootstrap table like this 
http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table/docs/examples.html

Comment: The data has been parsed through but nothing is happening, nothing is printed to the page :/ even though I know that there is data

Comment: Add the `print decoded_data['objects']` statement to your code and check the output of the `runserver` console.  Did it print the list of dicts?

Comment: Was a simple error on my part, thanks ever so much :)

Comment: @Nebbyyy What was error? I am stuck with same situation.